# How to get access token in sitefinity web services version 13

Tags: sitefinity-10

Request access token for Postman in sitefinity web services version 13

Tried with this https://community.progress.com/s/article/request-access-token-for-postman , but didn't got any expected result.
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/generate-access-key.

Comment: so what result or error did you get?